# Xcode, GitHub and third-party frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

I am planning to migrate my current local Git repository (managed by Xcode 5) to GitHub and found some tutorials on how to do this.

My questions is how can include third-party frameworks which I use with my project in GitHub.
The majority of them is not GitHub based, e.g. CorePlot (Google based), Parse.com (Zip Download).

How should I add these frameworks to my GitHub based Framework?

Comment: Poor soul using Parse... they are [shutting it down](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** to keep reference to other repo.

For [`CorePlot`](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/), which is a mercurial repo, you can use **[`git-hg`](https://github.com/offbytwo/git-hg)**, as described in "[Is there a way to use a Mercurial repository as Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9100572/6309)".
Or... use its [GitHub mirror repo for CorePlot](https://github.com/djw/core-plot/commits/master) directly as a submodule!