# How to insert a hg project into a git project?

Tags: git, mercurial

I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067283/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-mercurial-repository-as-git-submodule). I tried doing it this way to insert a mercurial project (namely the [eigen project](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org)) into a given git project.

When I try to clone it, I get something like

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/.../.git/
Fordere alle ?nderungen an
F?ge ?nderungss?tze hinzu
F?ge Manifeste hinzu
F?ge Datei?nderungen hinzu
F?gte 8820 ?nderungss?tze mit 28623 ?nderungen an 2757 Dateien hinzu (+4 K?pfe)
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/multikopter/foo/.git/hgremote/
Error: repository has at least one unnamed head: hg r8485
git-fast-import statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Alloc'd objects:       5000
Total objects:            0 (         0 duplicates                  )
  blobs  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
  trees  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
  commits:            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
  tags   :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
Total branches:           0 (         0 loads     )
  marks:           1024 (         0 unique    )
  atoms:              0
Memory total:          2282 KiB
   pools:          2048 KiB
 objects:           234 KiB
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pack_report: getpagesize()            =       4096
pack_report: core.packedGitWindowSize = 1073741824
pack_report: core.packedGitLimit      = 8589934592
pack_report: pack_used_ctr            =          0
pack_report: pack_mmap_calls          =          0
pack_report: pack_open_windows        =          0 /          0
pack_report: pack_mapped              =          0 /          0
---------------------------------------------------------------------

fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When using the flag `--force` this leads to a huge output and at least some commits get created in git as desired. However the process terminates with the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hg-fast-export/hg-fast-export.py", line 387, in <module>
    options.statusfile,authors=a,sob=options.sob,force=options.force))
  File "/usr/share/hg-fast-export/hg-fast-export.py", line 298, in hg2git
    ui,repo=setup_repo(repourl)
  File "/usr/share/hg-fast-export/hg2git.py", line 34, in setup_repo
return myui,hg.repository(myui,url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 112, in repository
    peer = _peerorrepo(ui, path, create)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 102, in _peerorrepo
    obj = _peerlookup(path).instance(ui, path, create)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 2478, in instance
    return localrepository(ui, util.urllocalpath(path), create)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 217, in __init__
    raise error.RepoError(_("repository %s not found") % path)
mercurial.error.RepoError: Projektarchiv  nicht gefunden
```

The last text means `repository not found` in German.

If I try to `git hg fetch` or `git hg pull` I get the exact same traceback. Further it seems that not all commits from the [eigen library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067283/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-mercurial-repository-as-git-submodule) are part of the git repository just created. When comparing the latest commits from `master` in git with the latest commits in mercurial one sees a dicrepancy of more than a year work (at least for me).

Can anybody verify this?

How can I overcome the problem? 
(GIT for the main project is set. The question is how to integrate the library in a matching version.)

Can anybody tell me a good alternative to `git-hg` if that might help?

Answer (score 0):

Main (for now) problem

> Error: repository has at least one unnamed head: hg r8485

Mercurial can have more than one head in named branch, Git-branching is ugly and weaker and Git can't handle this case. Namely, r8485 is *closed head* of `default` branch (but closing have sense only in some areas and only for Mercurial)

```
>hg log -r "heads(branch(default))"
changeset:   8485:59a7e404a93c
parent:      8483:df620f192518
user:        Christoph Hertzberg <chtz@informatik.uni-bremen.de>
date:        Thu Mar 17 19:38:45 2016 +0100
summary:     closing wrong default

changeset:   8820:1249b66e1544
tag:         tip
user:        Benoit Steiner <benoit.steiner.goog@gmail.com>
date:        Mon May 02 19:50:22 2016 -0700
summary:     Made a cast explicit
```

Possible solutions (require using Mercurial)

- Dummy-merge 8485 into current tip
- Partial clone of original repo, which exclude (all) leaf nodes