# Is there a way to use a Mercurial repository as Git submodule? (update)

Tags: git, mercurial

I would like to use a mercurial subrepo as as git submodule. I have followed the instruction posted to the exact same question here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067283/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-mercurial-repository-as-git-submodule). However even though all the setup steps completed successfully and without error when cloning the main repository and its subrepos I am running into errors.

Additionally the question at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067283/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-mercurial-repository-as-git-submodule) is 5 years old and I am afraid git has changed a lot in that time and therefore I feel this question merits an answer

When I clone I run the following:

> git clone --recursive

I get the following error:

> Cloning into
>   '/home/user/projects/mainrepo/project/hgsubrepo'...
>   repository does not exist. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.
>
> fatal: clone of
>   'git@bitbucket.org:mischief/ippan2.git/project/hgsubrepo'
>   into submodule path
>   '/home/user/projects/mainrepo/project/hgsubrepo'
>   failed Failed to clone 'project/hgsubrepo'. Retry scheduled
>   Cloning into
>   '/home/user/projects/mainrepo/project/hgsubrepo'...
>   repository does not exist. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.

If I interpret the results correctly git is trying to infer an remote URL for `hgsubrepo` but using `git` protocol not `mercurial` as I would expect given my understanding of the reponse in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067283/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-mercurial-repository-as-git-submodule)

Is there a different/better/new way to handle mercurial subrepos within git?

edit 1: 
the main repository lives in the local folder

> /home/user/projects/mainrepo

the hg repository lives in

> /home/user/project/mainrepo/projects/

Answer (score -1):

Try [git-remote-hg](https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-hg); add 'hg::' prefix to the URL of mercurial repository.